# Swift 3 Send Location as iMessage

Tags: ios, maps, swift3, imessage

I have made a classic "find-my-car-app" which saves a map location and navigates back there. I now want to implement a share button, to send a saved location via iMessage.

I have set up a MFMessageComposeViewController, in order to send a message body with the coordinates.

Using the URL method like: http://maps.apple.com/?ll=40.730610,-73.935242" does work, and opens the Maps app. What I'm missing is the map thumbnail in the message.

When sharing my location from iMessage or Maps, I get a nifty little map preview with the red pin in the message.
Copying the iMessage link on the Mac shows, that it's sent as a VCF card, but I found no way of sending a link in VCF format via iMessage.

Does anybody know how to get that map preview working?

Hope my question is clear enough!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this to create a VCF file: https://gist.github.com/naturaln0va/e1fed3f1d32ecf951aac

Than:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController ().addAttachmentURL(Global.locationVCardURLFromCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30, longitude: 40))!, withAlternateFilename: "vCard.loc.vcf")
```